# Directions from Source to Destinations via WayPoints using cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

am struck at how to find directions from source to destination via waypoints without opening external Google Map App in Device.In my app i used  [this plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps).

from this plugin i used this snippet but it's render to Google maps App in device. but i have requirement to do this in same app without rendering to outside

```
var yourLocation = null;
map.getMyLocation(function(location) {
yourLocation = location.latLng;

map.addMarker({
"position": yourLocation,
"title": "I am around here!"
}, function(marker) {
marker.showInfoWindow();
});

map.moveCamera({
"target": yourLocation,
"zoom": 12
});
});

map.on(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_CLICK, function(latLng) {
map.addMarker({
"position": latLng,
"title": "Destination"
 }, function(marker) {
marker.showInfoWindow();

setTimeout(function() {

  if (confirm("Do you want to go?")) {
    plugin.google.maps.external.launchNavigation({
      "from": yourLocation,
      "to": latLng
    });
  }
 }, 2000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

which version of cordova that you use in the project?

maybe:

This plugin is not compatible with Cordova-iOS 4.0.0. WKWebView is not supported. They have been huge changes in the API, and due to lack of time, there is no ETA when this plugin will be compatible. PRs are welcome!!